# ValueError: Related model u'app.model' cannot be resolved when adding admin and custom user in existing app

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-migrations

I have an existing app that has as lot of migrations and no users table. I am looking to add django admin and a custom user. I am hitting `Related model u'myapp.model' cannot be resolved` when I run `manage.py migrate`

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, myapp, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying myapp.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  <redacted>
  ValueError: Related model 'myapp.user' cannot be resolved
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the migration that adds the custom user, add this:

```
run_before = [
    ('admin', '__first__'),
]
```

Django admin's migration [depends on the first migration](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4c85beca9d8bf24573d741e26ea36295c69af5b2/django/contrib/admin/migrations/0001_initial.py#L9) so in `admin.0001_initial`, its dependency is ('myapp', '**first**')

Unfortunately since this is an old app, the first migration for `myapp` does not add a user table. Therefore the migration framework runs `myapp.0001_initial`, then runs `admin.0001_initial` at which point there is no user table.

I suppose django could have replace `__first__` with `__latest__` but I can see how that could introduce a whole host of other issues. I guess I am stuck with manually specifying the `run_before`

Comment: had literally the exact same issue and this worked just fine, thank you a lot